# Does JWT Authorization entirely depend upon the secret key?

Tags: authentication, security, jwt

According to my understanding a *JWT* can be broken down into a **Header**, **Payload** and a **Signature**. The **signature** is created using **Header**+**Payload**+**Secret**. The **secret** is stored by the *server* and is never shared.

When a *client* sends a *JWT* to the *server*. The *server* can authorize it by accessing the **Header** , **Payload** received from *JWT* and combine it with the **secret** to create a **Test Signature**. Then the *server* can check if **Test Signature** = **Signature** received from the *client* *JWT* and make sure the data is not altered.

• Does this mean that the entire *JWT* authorization is dependent on the **Secret** and the whole authorization process is compromised if it is leaked?

Comment: Yes. (And 10 more chatacters so I can actually add this comment. :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret is matter to **verify JWT**

This  diagram is normal sequence to use JWT for accessing resource by API call.

[image]
I would like to demo with real code.

Using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme) java-script library on node-js

*1. JWT generate step.*

function name: **generate_token()**

first function parameter: **secret**

second function parameter: **user name** (or payload)

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const jwtExpirySeconds = 600

const generate_token = (jwtKey, username) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, jwtKey, {
        algorithm: "HS256",
        expiresIn: jwtExpirySeconds,
    })
    console.log("JWT token:", token, '\n')
    const [header, payload, signature] = token.split(".")
    console.log("1) header:", header)
    console.log(JSON.parse(Buffer.from(header, "base64").toString("utf8")), '\n')
    console.log("2) payload:", payload)
    console.log(JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payload, "base64").toString("utf8")), '\n')
    console.log("3) signature:", signature)
}
const my_args = process.argv.slice(2);
generate_token(my_args[0], my_args[1]);
```

generate token with secret and user name

```
$ node generate_token.js my-secret user1
JWT token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NDA3NzQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NTk0MDgzNDR9.MMIxotVJjMBLFOg0nusePz4L62n7VZ4Q-fW_u392qDQ

1) header: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
{ alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }

2) payload: eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NDA3NzQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NTk0MDgzNDR9
{ username: 'user1', iat: 1659407744, exp: 1659408344 }

3) signature: MMIxotVJjMBLFOg0nusePz4L62n7VZ4Q-fW_u392qDQ
```

*2. Verify JWT step.*

function name: **verify_token()**

first function parameter: **secret**

second function parameter: **JWT token**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const verify_token = (jwtKey, token) => {
    try {
        payload = jwt.verify(token, jwtKey)
        console.log("JWT token verify:", payload, '\n')
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
            console.log("JWT token error: 401")
            return
        }
        // otherwise, return a bad request error
        console.log("JWT token error: 400")
    }
}
const my_args = process.argv.slice(2);
verify_token(my_args[0], my_args[1]);
```

*2.1 verify token with **correct secret** and JWT token*

```
$ node verify_token.js my-secret  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NDA3NzQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NTk0MDgzNDR9.MMIxotVJjMBLFOg0nusePz4L62n7VZ4Q-fW_u392qDQ
JWT token verify: { username: 'user1', iat: 1659407744, exp: 1659408344 }
```

*2.2 if verify token with **wrong secret** and same JWT token*

```
$node verify_token.js wrong-secret  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NDA3NzQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NTk0MDgzNDR9.MMIxotVJjMBLFOg0nusePz4L62n7VZ4Q-fW_u392qDQ
JWT token error: 401
```